# Phonegap Dialog Plugin is Working on android API (level 16) and it is not working on API (level 10)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I Have just written the simple code the when user press back key on the device it should ask the user "Are you sure you want to exit"? if user press yes then user will exit from the application and on pressing no button it will do nothing.

I am using phonegap 3.6.3 and Phonegap dialog Plugin I have added the plugin using

phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs

In Config xml I have added

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
```

And I have also checked

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
```

**JS Code :-**

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackKeyDown, false); //Listen to the User clicking on the back button
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
onDeviceReady: function() {
    navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working!!");
    initApp();
},
}};

function onBackKeyDown() {
navigator.notification.confirm(
"Are you sure you want to exit ?",  // message
onConfirm,                          // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
"Confirmation",                     // title
["Yes","No"]);                      // buttons label
// Prompt the user with the choice
}
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
if(buttonIndex==2){//If User selected No, then we just do nothing
    return;
}else{
    navigator.app.exitApp();// Otherwise we quit the app.
}
}
```

Same above code works fine in emulator for samsung galaxy s2 4.2.x (API 16)

[Image link](http://i61.tinypic.com/2itn67d.png)

Same code when i run it on emulator for samsung galaxy s2 2.3.x (API10) it is giving error 
"**NoSuchMethodError**"

[Image link](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2cza3ko.jpg)

I have read the document about the plugin and it say it support all android device.
so what am I doing wrong here?

So please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** I have removed my old message because below would be enough for everyone to make this Plugin work on all Android version.

---

## Cordova/PhoneGap: How to make dialog plugin work on all Android devices

---

**Here is the solution code:** https://github.com/aahad/Cordova-Plugin-dialogs--Android-all-versions/tree/master

---

Since Oct 16, 2014 (commit: 23bebf96f7a3388c7483afc0091faecf943692d3), the **dialog Plugin supports API 17 on-wards.**

This commit was to **properly** format **right-to-left** and **left-to-right languages**, as shown below in the snapshot. ([Check for setTextDirection API level](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/commit/23bebf96f7a3388c7483afc0091faecf943692d3))

Example: without any code modification

[image]

Now if there is **NO** need to properly format localized strings (or **no use of localization at all**) then if these lines are **removed** then the plugin support will be available from **API 14 on-wards**.

### Bring down to API 14 or 11

Currently dialog plugin is using device's light theme (`AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT`) that is available since **API 14**. So if it can be **changed** with something else like `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`, `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK`  or `AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL` as **these** are present since **API 11**. In this way we can make the plugin work on **API 11**.

I tried `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT` and found **exactly same results** as of with `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT`.

Using `AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL`, I see following result

[image]

Using `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK`, I see following result

[image]

### Bring down to API 7

`AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int theme)` was used to create instance of AlertDialog and this **two parameter based constructor** was added in **API 11**. While the basic original AlertDialog **constructor** that takes **single parameter** was present since **API 1**. So if there is **NO hard** need for a **specific theme** then by skipping the two parameter based constructor and by using single parameter based constructor we can easily get down to **API 7**.

#### 1. Notification - Since API 14 onwards

This is for someone who doesn’t need localization formatting in their app.

**Note: -** Even after removing these lines, still localized strings/text will appear as shown below; but the proper formatting will be out. Though it’s not visible in the snapshot but it is expected.

Results:

[image]
[image]

#### 2. Notification - Since API 7 onwards

This is for someone with **NO hard** requirement for any **specific theme or localization** and just need dialog functionality to work on **older devices**.

Results:

[image]

Comment: thanks AAhad for the fast reply.
so this plugin only works for api 17 onwards.So any advice how to achieve what i am trying on all android devices api level 10 onwards.

Comment: Let me think on it. BTW another suggestion would be to use JQueryMobile dialog; in one of my PhoneGap based project I used it for three platforms iOS, Android, Blackberry

Comment: I have found something and working on it, hopefully will help here.

Comment: I made it work on all Android devices from API 7 on-wards. Just trying to push it on git and will share it here with you :)

Comment: ohk u made it work using jquery mobile dailog for API 7 onwards thats grt :) just waiting for your git link.
thanks :)

Comment: I made some java code level changes and did not use of JQuery Mobile. I surely will publish it on git and will share all those findings that will help others as well. Just a bit busy and doing something but will publish by today at soonest possible :) Thanks

Comment: Grt work.
Thanks for ur grt effort and time. ;)
Thanks for sharing  :)